# Attaching an image to jQuery's autocomplete

Tags: jquery, image, autocomplete

I am having some difficulty adding an image to jQuery's autocomplete widget. I am pretty much a complete newcommer to jquery so I apologise for the simplicity of the problem. The function belwo is what I have been using but syntactically it is wrong (firebug throwing the error "TypeError: $(...).autocomplete(...).data(...) is undefined"), but I can't see where this is wrong. I can't even get onto the functionality aspect of it! Any guidance would be helpful. There are several questions on this tpoic already but unfortunately I couldn't manipulate the answers to fit my case (mainly because of my inexperience with jQuery rather than anything else).

The path to the avatar is "../avatars/user_id/user_id_thumbnail.jpeg" where user_id = an integer.

```
  $(function(){
    $( "#main_search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source:'../ajax/search.php', 
    minLength:1
    })
    .data( "autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var pic_path = '<img src="../avatars/' + item.value + '/' + item.value + '_thumbnail.jpeg">' ;
        return $( "<li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + pic_path + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so through trial and error AND reviewing questions, it was as simple as adding "ui" to autocomplete....thus..

```
 $(function(){
    $( "#main_search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source:'../ajax/search.php', 
    minLength:1
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var pic_path = '<img src="../avatars/' + item.id + '/' + item.id+ '_thumbnail.jpeg">' ;
        console.log(pic_path);
        return $( "<li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + pic_path + item.label + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
 });
```